# Перезапись переменных в функциях JS

Tags: javascript

Первый день изучаю JS.
Задача: спарсить курс биткоина в долларах, спарсить курс доллара в рублях, перемножить значения.

Проблема в том, что при вызове фунции *Btc2Rub()* вылетает ошибка "неизвестная переменная", но это логично, т.к. переменный объявляю в функциях.

Пробовал объявить "глобальные переменные" для btccourse и usdcourse, в надежде, что в функциях они перезапишутся, затем перемножатся.
Объявлял так: в первых строчках кода *var btccourse = 0;*, но переменная не перезаписывалась, оставаясь нулем.

Как мне решить эту проблему?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  getBtc();
  getUsd();
  Btc2Rub();
});


function getBtc() {
  $.get(
    "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",
    function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      btccourse = data.bpi.USD.rate_float;
      console.log("BTC = " + btccourse + " Usd");
    }
  )
};


function getUsd() {
  $.get(
    "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js",
    function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      usdcourse = data.Valute.USD.Value;
      console.log("USD = " + usdcourse + " Rub");
    }
  )
};

function Btc2Rub() {
  rubcourse = btccourse * usdcourse;
  console.log(rubcourse)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для выполнения асинхронного HTTP запроса используется метод [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), который лежит в основе всех `Ajax` запросов отправляемых при помощи `jQuery`.

Объект `jqXHR`, возвращаемый методом `$.ajax` реализует интерфейс `Promise`, дающий ему все свойства, методы и поведение `Promise`. Представляет результат успешного или неудачного завершения асинхронной операции.

Метод [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) принимает произвольное число промисов, и возвращает один [Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) объект. Обработчик `done` получит результаты каждого промиса, в вашем вопросе - два результата.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var btc = get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
  var usd = get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js');

  $.when(btc, usd).done(printResult);
});

function get(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}

function printResult([btc], [usd]) {
  var btccourse = btc.bpi.USD.rate_float;
  var usdcourse = usd.Valute.USD.Value;
  var rubcourse = btccourse * usdcourse;

  // Распечатаем результат.
  result.textContent = rubcourse;
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Вариант с использованием "сахара" в виде `async/await`, плюс обработка ошибок через `try...catch`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  Btc2Rub()
    .then(function(rubcourse) {
      // Распечатаем результат.
      result.textContent = rubcourse;
    });
});

function get(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}

async function Btc2Rub() {
  try {
    const btc = await get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json');
    const usd = await get('https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js');

    const btccourse = btc.bpi.USD.rate_float;
    const usdcourse = usd.Valute.USD.Value;

    return btccourse * usdcourse;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.when(getBtc(), getUsd()).then(Btc2Rub);
});


function getBtc() {
  return $.get(
    "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json",
    function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      return data.bpi.USD.rate_float;
    }
  )
};


function getUsd() {
  return $.get(
    "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/daily_json.js",
    function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      return data.Valute.USD.Value;
    }
  )
};

function Btc2Rub(btccourse, usdcourse) {
  var rubcourse = btccourse * usdcourse;
  console.log(rubcourse)
}
```

Comment: здравствуйте спарсить (сайт) получается можно и на js ? я думал только php может так делать; получается спарсить может любой язык который занимается web ?

Comment: @Leks в принципе подойдет любой язык, способный запросить данные с сайта, или запустить `curl`

Comment: @Stranger in the Q понятно спасибо

Comment: @Qwertiy, у Вас опечатка (`$.when(...).them`)

Comment: @Something, исправил.